# Permission issue with AWS lambda layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, javaagents, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to add javaagent to AWS lambda function. I created a layer and uploaded a zip file which has jar file. When I test the function I get

**Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /opt/xxxxx.jar**

But I can clearly see inside
**-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1219876 Nov 30 05:30 xxxxx.jar**

The only issue i see is it is with root permission. How do i upload so that it has current user permissions ?

Comment: Is the jar manifest there?

Comment: Yes. It is there

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?  I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It works when i select Runtime as JAVA8(Corretto) or JAVA11(Corretto). Some issue with JAVA8